# how to add a fixed column in power query?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a few huge datasets and I want to append them together. To not lose the data source name (bla), I would like to add in 1 column, of each data set, the data source name (`bla`). Many thanks in advance.

Expected Result using M language.

```
Date       Amount   data.source
1/1/2020   20         bla
1/1/2020   20         bla
1/1/2020   20         bla
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, TableA and TableB are two source queries (your huge datasets) and a column is added to each before appending.

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({ Table.AddColumn( TableA, "data.source", each "TableA"), Table.AddColumn( TableB, "data.source", each "TableB")})
in
    Source
```